# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied

Tags: flask

I managed to delete some id, but I still get this error:
can someone help me?

```
@app.route("/audio/delete", methods=["GET"])
def delete():
  id = request.args.get("id")
  db = create_connection()
  db.execute('''DELETE FROM mp3player WHERE ID = ?''', id)
  db.commit()
  db.close()
  return redirect("/audio/", code=302)

app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try format strings:

```
db.execute("DELETE FROM mp3player WHERE ID = {myid}".format(myid=myid))
```